# using smtp class in python to send automated emails

Tags: python

So i am experimenting with the SMTP module in python and the code i was using, wasnt working. i found a solution on stack overflow which literally was the same code as mine but worked.
Can someone please find a difference or tell me why my code wasnt working
my code is the second block

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('example@gmail.com','password')
server.sendmail('example@gmail.com','recipient@gmail.com','msg')
server.close()
print("SUCCESS")




import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smpt.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('example@gmail.com','password')
server.sendmail('example@gmail.com','recipient@gmail.com','msg')
server.close()
print("SUCCESS")
```

there is no literal difference but the first one works and the second one doesnt

Comment: Those two are not exactly the same.  Check again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant to type

`smtp.gmail.com` instead of `stmp.gmail.com`

Next time try diffchecker.com or something similar to make sure the two blocks of code are actually the same, because in this case they aren't in a very important way.

Comment: Thank you so much i thought i was going crazy

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't configure your google account to accept your smtp requests.

> To be able to send emails via your Gmail account, you need to provide access to it for your application. You can Allow less secure apps or take advantage of the OAuth2 authorization protocol. It’s a way more difficult but recommended due to the security reasons.

https://julien.danjou.info/sending-emails-in-python-tutorial-code-examples/